# cannot read sms and start new service on receive sms in android

Tags: android, sms

my application read incoming message and start service when sms is received.
when i install it in mobile it is not working

following is the code

my broad cast receiver file

```
public class readsms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


//       getting bundle

        Bundle getdata=intent.getExtras();
        System.out.println("i got msg first");
        if(getdata==null){
            return;
        }

        Object[] pdus=(Object[])getdata.get("pdus");
        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            String fromAddress = message.getOriginatingAddress();
            String fromDisplayName = fromAddress;
            System.out.println(message.getMessageBody().toString());
            Intent di=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            di.putExtra("from", fromAddress);
            di.putExtra("msg", message.getMessageBody().toString());
            context.startService(di);

        }
    }

}
```

my service file

```
public class MainActivity extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId){
        Bundle getdata=intent.getExtras();
        String msg=getdata.getString("msg");
        String from="from :"+getdata.getString("from")+"/n"+msg;
        String destination="phone number";
        SmsManager mysms=SmsManager.getDefault();
        mysms.sendTextMessage(destination, null,from , null, null);
        return startId;

    }
}
```

my manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.projectx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:name=".MainActivity">

        </service>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

please point me what i m missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You must have registered the BroadCast Receiver class in your mainfest file.  Use this code:

```
<receiver android:name="readsms"/>
```

in your mainfest file.

Comment: Thnks rishabh let me check this

Comment: sure,if any problem let me know :)

Comment: I am not getting any error log but still app is not able to forward incoming msg to a particular number

Comment: yes i know that.You must have register your broadcast.Put this code <receiver android:name="readsms"/>  in your mainfest under application context.

Comment: i did what you say still i am not getting any toast notification i put afterwards also nor i got msg on the number i mentioned in service